# Xlsx in access problems

Tags: ms-access

I currently use Microsoft Access 2003 and am sending emails with an xls attachments. Is it possible to update the format to send in xlsx. The docmd statement I use doesn't recognize the format when I change the acformat to acformatxlsx.

Comment: Can you read/write xlsx files in your Excel?

Comment: If you can, it could be done, I do it...

Comment: Could explain what you mean by excel writing xlsx files? The email I send are part of a query in access.

Comment: Can you, in Excel, save a file as xlsx? double-click on xlsx file and open it in Excel?

Comment: Please read: [Open an Office Excel 2007 workbook in an earlier version of Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-an-Office-Excel-2007-workbook-in-an-earlier-version-of-Excel-868E7F65-7757-4CAA-830D-A8933A5941CD?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). and see if you should [download the Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint File Formats](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3).

Answer (score 2):

Access 2003 doesn't know the XLSX format. You need Access 2007 or above.

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass that without upgrading access? I changed the format of the email attachments to html but it does not work when viewing them from a blackberry phone.

Comment: ad 1: No. ad 2: Then don't use either the html format or BlackBerry phones.

Answer (score 2):

If your Excel writes Xlsx files, It could be done:

1. You have to work with the Excel Object.

   ```
   Dim ApXl as Object, XlWb as Object, XlWs as Object
   Dim TableOrQueryNameOrSELECTstatement as String
   Set ApXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   ```
2. Add/open a Workbook, and save as [Xlsx file format](https://blogs.office.com/2009/07/07/use-the-vba-saveas-method-in-excel-2007/): **51** (Acc2003 doesn't know the constant).

   ```
   Set XlWb = ApXL.Application.Workbooks.Add
   XlWb.SaveAs strFilePath, 51
   ```
3. Add/open a Worksheet.

   ```
   Set XlWs = XlWb.Worksheets(1)
   ```
4. [Open a DAO.Recordset, and send it to the worksheet, and save it](http://btabdevelopment.com/export-a-table-or-query-to-excel/).

   `xlWS.Range("A1").Select
   Dim rst as DAO.Recordset, fld as Variant
   Set rst = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(TableOrQueryNameOrSELECTstatement)
   For Each fld In rst.Fields
       ApXL.Application.ActiveCell = fld.Name
       ApXL.Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
   Next
   rst.MoveFirst
   xlWSh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
   XlWb.Save`
5. Don't forget to Close your objects, and set them to Nothing.

Comment: If you run Excel 2007 or newer, this code should run just fine. If not, please note the [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint 2007 File Formats](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3). More about it [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-an-Office-Excel-2007-workbook-in-an-earlier-version-of-Excel-868E7F65-7757-4CAA-830D-A8933A5941CD?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). Without this Compatibility Pack, earlier excel can't save files in xslx format.